# ReactJS check value in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check `v.name` if exist:

```
{value.district && value.district.length > 0 ? value.district.map((v,i) => 
    <span key={i}>{v.name} </span>
) : 'Nothing'}
```

This json:

```
{
   "current_page":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":9,
         "hash":"X3JTgxOQlWk0ZIMBVe41",
         "province":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"yyyy"
         },
         "city":{
            "id":3,
            "name":"xxx"
         },
         "district":[
            {
               "id":107,
               "name":"blah blah"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":10,
         "hash":"IObmLaVewiNf9cn1ETQy",
         "province":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"zzzzzzzzzzz"
         },
         "city":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"rrrrrrrrrrrrrr"
         },
         "district":[
            null
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of null

I tried:

```
{v.name ? v.name : null}
```

But still got error. how can I do this?

Comment: because v is null

Comment: @adel yes, how can I skip this?

Comment: Try v?.name (optional chaining operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to solve this check if the item in array is valid or not null like this:

```
 {value.district && value.district.length > 0 ? value.district.map((v,i) => 
 (v?<span key={i}>{v.name} </span>:null)): 'Nothing'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

You can replace `{v.name}` with a guard to check that `v` is not null, which could be either of:

- `{v && v.name}`
- `{v ? v.name : null}` (which is very close to what you tried, but please note the difference - `v.name` throws the error when `v` is null so you can't use that to check)

Or filter the array before `map`-ing it:

```
{value.district && value.district.length > 0 ? value.district.filter(v => v).map((v,i) =>
    <span key={i}>{v.name} </span>
) : 'Nothing'}
```

the additional `.filter(v => v)` simply removes any falsy values, such as `null`.